# Create an article entry without image

Tags: media

All I want is to post a video embed, but the drupal form is forcing me to use an image for each, otherwise I can't upload my post.

[image: Can't upload without image]

Is there a way to override that field in particular?

Comment: First things first, how have you made this field required? And if it wasn't you, how do you know changing it won't break anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can un-require the field. Navigate to:

> /admin/structure/types/manage/[content_type]/fields

and un-require there.